# Spring Framework and Spring Security SAML (without Spring Boot)

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm in the process of migrating away from the spring-security-saml module that has been deprecated to the new SAML support built into Spring Security 5+.  I'd really like to not have to migrate this entire project from Spring Framework to String Boot at this time, so does anyone know if there is documentation on how to get Spring Security with SAML working on vanilla Spring Framework, everything I've seen has been only Spring Boot.  Any help would be majestic!

Comment: The Spring Security reference documentation describes what Spring Boot does and how to override that behaviour. You can follow [that section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2login-sansboot) to see which components are needed if you are not using Boot.